# Use running instance of background script in extension popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've defined background script **global.js** in my extension's manifest file, but I need to access it's variables in my **popup.js** which is loaded by html file when the extension button is clicked. If I load **global.js** the same way I load **popup.js**, it creates new instance of it, but I want to access the instance running in the background.

---

In background running **global.js**:

```
url = "";
// some change
url = "example.com"
```

Opened **popup.html** loads:

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

**popup.js**:

```
console.debug(url)
// returns ""
```

---

**HOW TO RETURN "example.com"?**
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [chrome.extension.getBackgroundpage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage). Something like the following should work in popup.js.

```
var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
console.log(bg.url);
```

Comment: Thanks, but since getExtensionTabs is deprecated and I was not sure if and how to use getViews, I used chrome.runtime.connect which works perfect for me :)

Comment: `getBackgroundPage` not `getExtensionTabs`